# Correct form of word "write"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-request

Is that right to ask someone formally

> Are you going to **write** GRE this month?

or what would be the correct form of

> Are you going to **write** GRE this month?

Comment: "Are you going to _take_ the GRE this month?" in US English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a suspicion that you mean to ask whether or not the person will participate in the GRE exam, not create one.

As an American, I would say

> [take](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take)
>
> 17. **a** :  to undertake and make, do, or perform
>       <*take a test*>
>
> Are you going to **take** the GRE this month?

I have heard *write* used in this sense, however I don't know if it is considered correct/natural in other English speaking countries. I have only heard *write* in this sense for nonnative speakers. I personally think it is weird to use *write* in this sense. You're also missing "the", as in *the GRE*.

Answer (score 0):

This would be correct. However the correct expression would be:

"Are you going to write the GRE this month?"

Write means to makes marks that represent words or numbers on a certain document http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/write. Seeing as the GRE is a test, it would also be appropriate to use other phrases such as "Are you going to sit the GRE this month?" meaning entirely the same thing.

One thing I noticed from your sentence is the missing definate article "the" which needs to go before GRE as it is a specific test that requires an article to introduce it to the statement.

If you need further clarification/help don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: Yes  but is *to write a test* idiomatic in any dialect of English?